# jQueryUI: Select dropdown not displaying correctly in tab layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, tabs

In this example I'm trying to create a tab layout, in which each tab will contain a dropdown list. I have to do it this way because there will be navigation between the tabs and initially only the first tab is enabled.

Unfortunately the dropdown list is not displaying correctly on the tabs that were disabled before. Instead of a full-sized dropdown list only a small piece of it can be seen (pic below). How to make it display in its full size?

The code example consists of HTML+JS and I'm using jQueryUI framework.

https://jsfiddle.net/fthjhfe8/3/

[image: Select dropdown not displaying correctly]

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav"><a href="#tabs-1">TAB 1</a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav"><a href="#tabs-2">TAB 2</a></li>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav"><a href="#tabs-3">TAB 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <select name="select1" id="select1">
            <option disabled selected> -- select -- </option>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <select name="select2" id="select2">
            <option disabled selected> -- select -- </option>
            <option>Option A</option>
            <option>Option B</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <select name="select3" id="select3">
            <option disabled selected> -- select -- </option>
            <option>Option I</option>
            <option>Option II</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<input id="previous" type="submit" value="<< Previous">
<input id="next" type="submit" value="Next >>">
```

JS:

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs');
$tabs.tabs({ disabled: [1, 2] });
$("#select1").selectmenu();
$("#select2").selectmenu();
$("#select3").selectmenu();
$("#previous").button();
$("#next").button();

var minTabs=0;
var maxTabs=3;
var currentTab=0;
var activeTab=0;

function previous() {
    if (currentTab==minTabs) {
      return;
    }
    currentTab--;
    $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active",currentTab);
  }

function next() {
    if (currentTab==maxTabs) {
      return;
    }
    if ($('#select'+(currentTab+1)).val() === null) {
        alert("A selection must be made!");
        return;
    }
    currentTab++;
    if (currentTab > activeTab) {
      activeTab = currentTab;
    }
    $('#tabs').tabs('enable',currentTab).tabs("option", "active",currentTab);
}

$("#previous").bind('click', previous);
$("#next").bind('click', next);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that calling jquery tabs would hide tab2 and tab3, the jquery would not be able to apply `selectmenu()` to the corresponding select tags. So you would need to add it before you enable jquery tabs.

```
 var $tabs = $('#tabs');

$("#select1").selectmenu();
$("#select2").selectmenu(); // moved before calling $.tabs
$("#select3").selectmenu(); // moved before calling $.tabs
$tabs.tabs({ disabled: [1, 2] });
$("#previous").button();
$("#next").button();

var minTabs=0;
var maxTabs=3;
var currentTab=0;
var activeTab=0;

function previous() {
    if (currentTab==minTabs) {
      return;
    }
    currentTab--;
    $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active",currentTab);
  }

function next() {
    if (currentTab==maxTabs) {
      return;
    }
    currentTab++;
    if (currentTab > activeTab) {
      activeTab = currentTab;    
    }
    $('#tabs').tabs('enable',currentTab).tabs("option", "active",currentTab);
}


$("#previous").bind('click', previous);
$("#next").bind('click', next);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fthjhfe8/2/